# Android: start listener across classes

Tags: java, android

Hey I am currently working myself my way into custom views on Android but I now run into a problem setting a listener. If I call the listener from within the custom view class, everything works, but I want to set the listener from my MainActivity which is where I am running into problems right now. Every time, I call the Listener from my MainActivity I just get a nullpointer, no matter what I pass to the method. Here the code of the custom class

```
public class RoundKnobButton extends RelativeLayout implements OnGestureListener {

public interface RoundKnobButtonListener {
    public void onStateChange(boolean newstate) ;
    public void onRotate(int percentage);
}


public RoundKnobButtonListener m_listener;

public void SetListener(RoundKnobButtonListener l) {
    m_listener = l;
}
```

and if I call the Listener from within this class like

```
     SetListener(new RoundKnobButtonListener() {
            public void onStateChange(boolean newstate) {

            }

            public void onRotate(final int percentage) {
            System.out.println(percentage); 
     }
                });
```

It returns the value perfectly. Now, when I want to do something like

```
rv=(RoundKnobButton) findViewById(R.id.jogView);
rv.SetListener(new RoundKnobButton.RoundKnobButtonListener() {
public void onStateChange(boolean newstate) {
}

public void onRotate(final int percentage) {
    System.out.println(percentage); 
        }
    });
```

in my MainActivity, I get

```
02-10 14:31:45.354: W/dalvikvm(19006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418259a8)
02-10 14:31:45.360: E/AndroidRuntime(19006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 14:31:45.360: E/AndroidRuntime(19006): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 14:31:45.360: E/AndroidRuntime(19006):    at  .buildUI( .java:191)
02-10 14:31:45.360: E/AndroidRuntime(19006):    at  .access$6( .java:125)
02-10 14:31:45.360: E/AndroidRuntime(19006):    at  .onPostExecute( .java:334)
```

Where line 191 refers to `rv.SetListener(new RoundKnobButton.RoundKnobButtonListener()`

I already tried passing all kinds of parameters with all kinds of casts, but nothing seems to help here.

Thanks in advance, Alex

Comment: Did you check rv is not null  and has been set whit this id R.id.jogView in your xml layout file ?

Comment: You are right, it is actually null, but now I am wondering why it is not getting any value 0o the findViewById is among  all the others (for buttons etc.) that do work. Is there anything further I need to think of?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KevDev, I found the problem. I called

```
super(context);
```

but I shold've called `super(context,attrs);` in my constructer as it is `public RoundKnobButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` otherwise it of course can't return the ID

Thanks